# Create an instance from a closure

Tags: elisp, sicp

I am reading the example [3.1Assignment and Local State from SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-20.html#%_sec_3.1.1)

```
#+begin_src scheme 
(define (make-withdraw balance)
  (lambda (amount)
    (if (>= balance amount)
        (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
               balance)
        "Insufficient funds")))
(define W1 (make-withdraw 100))
(W1 50)
(W1 30)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 20
```

Practice with elisp

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp lexical t
(defun make-withdraw(balance)
  (lambda (amount)
    (if (>= balance amount)
        (progn (setq balance (- balance amount))
               balance)
        "Insufficient funds")))
(make-withdraw 10)
(defvar W1 (make-withdraw 100))
(funcall (W1 30))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: W1
```

Did not work as expected, experiment it interactively

Case 1: call `make-withdraw` directly  and return a closure

```
;; lexical-binding t 
ELISP> (make-withdraw 100)
(closure
 ((balance . 100)
  t)
 (amount)
 (if
     (>= balance amount)
     (progn
       (setq balance
             (- balance amount))
       balance)
   "Insufficient funds"))
```

Case 2: Assign it to a W1, yet return a common function rather than a closure

```
ELISP> (defvar W1 (funcall (withdraw 100)))
W1
ELISP> W1
(lambda
  (amount)
  (if
      (>= balance amount)
      (progn
        (setq balance
              (- balance amount))
        balance)
    "Insufficient funds"))
```

How could create an instance `W1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ELISP> (defvar W1 (funcall (withdraw 100)))
```

`withdraw` is not `make-withdraw` -- you've called something else.

```
ELISP> W1
(lambda ...)
```

And that something else was not defined with `lexical-binding` active, otherwise you would be seeing a closure.

As for this...

```
(make-withdraw 10)
(defvar W1 (make-withdraw 100))
(funcall (W1 30))
```

You're assigning a function to a *variable* `W1` which means (as you know from your other recent questions here) that you *cannot* use `(W1 30)` but would instead have to use `(funcall W1 30)`

Comment: ty, I got the idea, since elisp does not evaluate the first element(just examine), so a func-definition should be evaluated on other position (ready for execute).